# Grant Azure Machine Learning access to SQL Server on Virtual Machine with ACL

Tags: sql-server, azure, machine-learning, acl, azure-machine-learning-service

We are in the process of setting up Azure Machine Learning within our Azure instance. Our SQL Server sits on a virtual machine and access is restricted using ACL's

We have looked extensively for a virtual IP or an IP within Machine Learning to add to the ACL but we cannot find it.

We have tested access by entering 0.0.0.0/0 to our ACL which allows access to ML  but obviously this isnt secure and not something that we wish to continue with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reaching out internally to try and get some more information, will update when able...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure public IP address are published and refreshed at regular intervals it can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653

You can use these to specify the restricted IP range for access

Comment: Thanks very much, ive been away for a few days so unable to reply. Would i need to enter all of these? Or is there some way of uploading this file?

Comment: Any more information on the question I asked above this? Looking at the XML list available this supplies many IP Address's and are you saying i need to enter all of them into my NSG ACL? Is this not a security risk? Surely by adding the many CIDR's im opening up my SQL instance to all ML users in that Azure region?